# Accessing Apple Hardware Tool on MacBook Air 2010 running Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, macos

I charged my MacBook Air (Late 2010) up to 100% charge overnight however my battery died within 1 hour. Because of this I want to use the Apple Hardware Tool (AHT) to diagnose the issue.

My Mac is 4 years old and holds up to 70%-75% of its original capacity (6,700mAh).

I have tried holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key when booting my computer however it boots up normally.

How would I accesses the AHT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest) you find an extensive list with various links to AHT images.

The direct links to the AHT of your model are: 13" [MacBookAir3,2](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-4267-A.dmg) or 11" [MacBookAir3,1](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/022-4704-A.dmg).

To copy the .diagnostics folder, mount the dmg
 and enter for the MacBookAir3,2 AHT:

```
sudo cp -R /Volumes/AHTBOne/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics /System/Library/CoreServices
```

or for the MacBookAir3,1 AHT:

```
sudo cp -R /Volumes/AHTBTwo/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics /System/Library/CoreServices
```

and enter an admin password at the prompt.

After copying the folder successfully try again to boot to Diagnostic Mode.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not tried this yet since my Mac is working normally again. I shall mark it as answered since it looks like it should work and it will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your AHT feature will have been lost when you upgraded to Yosemite.

You can restore it by inserting the **Applications Install** disc that was supplied with your computer and typing the following command, putting in the actual name of the disc where indicated...

```
sudo cp -R /Volumes/[name of disc]/System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics /System/Library/CoreServices
```

You will of course be able to run the diagnostics directly from the install disc.

- Actually read the question properly and of course your Air doesn't have an optical drive - did it come with any re-installation media? If not you now know where the actual test file should go, if anyone can supply you with the required file

Comment: No, I don't have the disk. I think (but I'm not sure) I still have a Mavericks install application on my external hard drive. Could I use the AHT using that?

Comment: I've checked and your Air should have come supplied with a USB software installer - not sure about the Mavericks installer, I will check shortly but I doubt it will have the appropriate AHT build for your Mac.

Comment: If you're looking to download the AHT for your Air the specific one you need is AHT build 3s142.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I can get it? I don't have the installation media since I got it second hand.

Comment: Start with Google and search for **Apple 3s142** - there is a chance I have a copy at home as I'm a magpie for such things (you never know when these things will come in handy), will check when I finish work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21820/discussion-between-scunnerdarkly-and-apydeveloper).